# Sencha Touch NestedList getDetailCard trouble

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm having a bit of trouble using a Nested List and a detailCard. I currently have a nested list displaying a simple tree of categories of CDs. It looks like this:

```
LCMobile.views.CategoriesList = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, { 
    layout: 'card', 
    items: categoriesList 
}); 

var categoriesList = new Ext.NestedList({ 
    title: 'Categories',
    store: categoryStore, 
    displayField: 'title', 
    getDetailCard: function(item, parent) { 
        var itemData = item.attributes.record.data; 
        parentData = parent.attributes.record.data; 
        LCMobile.detailCard.update(itemData); 
        this.backButton.setText(parentData.title); 
        return LCMobile.detailCard; 
    } 
});
```

And my detailCard looks like this:

```
LCMobile.detailCard = new Ext.Panel({ 
    id: 'detailPanel', 
    layout: 'card', 
    scroll: 'vertical', 
    styleHtmlContent: true, 
    items: '', 
    tpl: ["<h3>{title}</h3>", "<img height='50px' width='50px' src='/images/covers/{sku}.jpg'>{description}" ] 
});
```

Problem I am having is that the detailCard will show up once, and the back button will work, but it will only work one time, and error out after that. Says 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.
I'm pretty sure there's another step I'm missing somewhere not assigning the previous card, but I'm at a bit of a loss, and in the API the only thing I could find was about the prev() method for cards, and it only made me more confused. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Though the error isn't clear to me, I hope you are creating "LCMobile.detailCard" only once. The problem may come if you try to create another panel with same id. And what is "this.backButton"? NestedList automatically creates those buttons.